# How can I prevent this from returning a long list of None values?

Tags: python, list, null

This script determines which websites out of a possible number of websites has the data that I want. `z` runs all of the potential websites through `data_grabber(item)`, which returns a list of the indexes of all the valid URLs. It also includes `None` values for the websites that weren't valid.

```
import requests

a = range(0, 10)
b = 'http://www.grandexchangecentral.com/include/gecgraphjson.php?jsid=%r'

websites = []
for i in a:
    result = b % a[i]
    websites.append(result)

def data_grabber(item): 
    url = item
    r = requests.get(url, headers={'Referer': 'www.grandexchangecentral.com'})
    data = r.json
    if data != None:
        return websites.index(item)

z = [data_grabber(x) for x in websites]
z1 =  filter(None, z)
```

This returns `[None, None, 2, None, None, None, 6, None, 8, None]`, which `z1` shortens to `[2, 6, 8]`. The only problem with this is that the list of possible websites can get very long, and so it can take a few minutes to generate many `None` placeholders in `z`. Would it be possible to make prevent `z` from generating `None` items? Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: Now I realize that it's actually `data_grabber` taking most of the time. Still nice to know this though.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the presence of Nones is costing you minutes of runtime -- are you sure that's the bottleneck?

Comment: The current bottleneck is that the way I verify the websites takes a fairly long tome. But, the list of potential websites can stretch upwards of 20,000, so calculating a few thousand `None` values will take a few minutes.

Comment: @user1709173 It's fantastically unlikely it will take any significant time compared to loading a webpage from the network.

Comment: It's the retrieval and analysis of the 20K pages that's taking the time.  All the time is being spent *in* data_grabber().  Whether or not a None is returned is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: Oh. I see. I guess I assumed that was taking up time as well. This was a pretty pointless question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @DSM that it seems unlikely this is costing you too much time. But this will avoid that:

```
filter(None, (data_grabber(x) for x in websites))
```

Using the parentheses instead of brackets will make a generator of `data_grabber` results, which `filter` will then consume, building up the result list without ever making the intermediate list with `None`s in it.

---

Just a test of your claim about timings:

```
>>> %timeit filter(None, [None for x in range(100000)])
100 loops, best of 3: 9.22 ms per loop
```

Not exactly the same thing, but this makes a list of 100,000 `None`s and then filters them all out in 9 milliseconds on my computer.

Comment: I wondered for a second if the problem was really with `websites.index` -- that could be really slow if it's always finding what it's looking for at the end, and should be avoided -- but even 50k only takes 30s or so in the worst case..